# missing operator in query sum expression vb net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2013

```
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select sum[Shark Individual Weight] from FishCaught'", myConnection)
Dim ds As DataTable = New DataTable()
da.Fill(ds)
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds

myConnection.Close()
```

Hello. I am using vb.net connecting to ms access. I keep getting error 'missing operator in query expression'. I would like to know what's wrong with my sql statement.

```
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select Sum([Shark Individual Weight]) From FishCaught Where ([OperationID]) = '" & TextBoxOpID4.Text & "'", myConnection)
    Dim ds As DataTable = New DataTable()
    da.Fill(ds)
    DataGridView2.DataSource = ds
```

I think my SQL syntax is wrong. How should write it actually? I get this error 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression'. If i just write ' Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select Sum([Shark Individual Weight]) From FishCaught', the sum will be display. So i think there's error in WHERE clause. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `sum[Shark Individual Weight]` looks wrong supposed to be it is `sum(fieldname)` but in your code the `Shark Individual Weight` is not a field

Comment: but in ms access, shark individual weight is a field

Answer (score 0):

this is your code

```
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select sum[Shark Individual Weight] from FishCaught'", myConnection)
Dim ds As DataTable = New DataTable()
da.Fill(ds)
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds

myConnection.Close()
```

Supposed to be the code must be like this

```
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select sum(The_Name_Of_The_Field) from FishCaught'", myConnection)
Dim ds As DataTable = New DataTable()
da.Fill(ds)
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds

myConnection.Close()
```

Is that so, try this **FINAL**

```
 Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select sum(Shark__Individual_Weight) as FishWeight from FishCaught'", myConnection)
    Dim ds As DataTable = New DataTable()
    da.Fill(ds)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds

    myConnection.Close()
```

Try to change `Shark Individual Weight` to `Shark_Individual_Weight` it will work

Comment: thanks for your response. but the code still produce the same error

Comment: OleDb exception was unhandled

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'sum[Shark_Individual_Weight]'.

Comment: BRB we will fix this

Comment: I know your error now and thats because of the field I will edit my answer please wait.

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'sum[Shark_Individual_Weight]'.

Comment: see the final answer

Comment: Sorry for being late. It keeps producing the same error

Comment: can you help me with this code? i add where clause but i got error. this is the code --> "Select Sum([Shark Individual Weight]) From FishCaught Where [OperationID] = ' " & TextBoxOpID4.Text & " ' "

Comment: if you believe that your problem is not related here, u are welcome to post a new one. Im sure someone will help u and also me

Answer (score 0):

*Sum* is a function and you have a disturbing *single quote*, thus:

```
"Select Sum([Shark Individual Weight]) From FishCaught"
```

Comment: i got this error ' No value given for one or more required parameters.'

Comment: This indicates a missing or misspelled field name.

Comment: Thanks my program works! DataGridView1.DataSource should be DataGridView2.DataSource

Answer (score 0):

`"Select Sum([field name]) From FishCaught"` should work. Have you checked the field name in database, it should not contain any space. To make field name more readable you can replace any spaces with "_".

Comment: I already get the correct code, thank anyway. however, there are some problem with the code when i add where clause. If possible, could you help me with that?